# Why is the value I get from my Database not public?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I am able to recieve a specific value from my mySQL database with php in Android.
I can display the recieved value with a toast but only if I put the toast in my try and catch method like this:

```
public void loadProducts() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, GLOBALBANNER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {
                        JSONArray products = new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject productObject = products.getJSONObject(0);
                        id = productObject.getInt("ID");
                        imageURL = productObject.getString("Image");
                        playstorelink = productObject.getString("PlayStoreLink");
                        isDislaying = productObject.getInt("isDisplaying");
                        displayingTimes = productObject.getInt("DisplayingTimes");


                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL MainActivity: " + playstorelink , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

but as soon as I try to access this value from the onCreate method it gives me Null:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //configuration.setUseDebugShake(false);


        loadProducts();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL MainActivity: " + playstorelink , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Why am I only able to use the value inside the try and catch method?
I want it to be public.

I declared my variables public:

```
public int id;
public String playstorelink;
public String imageURL;
public int isDislaying;
public int displayingTimes;
```

I'm pretty new to Android and have no clue why this is not working.
I simply need to work with those 5 values from the database.

Here is my PHP Script:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "censored";
    $password = "censored";
    $dbName = "censored";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());

    }

    $response = array();

    $sql_query = "SELECT ID, Image, PlayStoreLink, isDisplaying, DisplayingTimes FROM globalbanner";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

             array_push($response, $row);

        }


    }else{
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = 'No data';
    }

echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `loadProducts` finishes when the request is sent, not when the response is received. When the response is available, the response listener is executed. At that time, your `onCreate` already finished.

Comment: @f1sh Okay thanks, so what should I do to work with the values? playstorelink  etc